# Getting notification / listener when action is performed (chimpChat / monkeyrunner tool)

Tags: java, android, listener, functional-testing

I want to get a notification if someone has performed an action in an android app from outside of the app. I don't want to make any (android) code changes. To do the actions I use the Chimpchat.jar, the .jar that the monkeyrunner tool uses.
To be clear: Can I get a notification or register listeners on components from outside of the app? 
e.g.

1. Run my android app
2. My java application links into the device with chimpChat via the adb
3. The user touches a button
4. My java application gets a notification what was performed 
   => am I able to get that information? If not, am I able to get the information on which position the tab was?

Hopefully it's clear what I want to do.

Thanks, soeren

Comment: I guess that you can receive where you tapped but I do not think that you can register a listener. You should look into monkey_recorder.py tool (it shows you where you've tapped). HTH!

Comment: I took a look at the [MonkeyRecorder's sources](http://androidxref.com/4.1.1/xref/sdk/monkeyrunner/src/com/android/monkeyrunner/recorder/MonkeyRecorder.java) and played around with it. It grabs the information from screenshots ya? I just need the position where I've tabbed without that jFrame that shows the current visible screen. Where does the monkeyRecorder get that info from? So there must be an method, that provides that information.
I don't know how to get tab infos from the monkeyRecorder, it just shows a snapshot of the current device?

Comment: I have an other suggestion:
Is it possible to deploy a library with the Android AUT that is able to register listeners (e.g. a mouselistener for the screen) and give the events through the adb to my java application?
Following @Yuri s suggestion with monkey_recorder I was not able to get the info, where I have tabbed and I don't find any examples about it.